# how to design table for accessing the different places

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, database-design

The tables are for users to access different places

The design as below:

user table:

```
<user>
userid
username
place          (the row define access rights)
```

place table:

```
<place>
placeid
placename
floor
```

My thoughts:

three places and placeid are 001,002,003
one user and  userid is 001 to aceess these three places

```
<user>
userid     username       place
001        john           001,002,003


<place>
placeid    placename   floor
001        A           1 
002        B           2 
003        C           3
004        D           4
```

My question is,

in "user" table, the attribute "place" contains many placeids, 
and separate by a comma, this design is fine or bad ?
It needs to separate the place values from "user" table ?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a good idea. Make a separate table to store the relationship:

```
<users-places>
userid  placeid
1       1
1       2
1       3
```

Indexing your approach would not be straight forward - although possible.

Use the name "users-places" as it implies what 2 tables it relates. Change the name if you significantly store more information about this relationship - ie, you start adding columns to this new table.

Also, name your tables in the plural form. Singular is reserved for class names. Tables are thought of as collections.

Answer (score 2):

Using a comma delimited list to do a many to many relationship is bad design. You should use an intermediate table instead:

```
<user>
userid
username

<place>
placeid
placename
floor

<accessrights>
userid
placeid
```

Instead of putting "1,2,3" in user.place for userid 001, then, you put three rows in accessrights, all with userid 001 and one with each placeid.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all,

I modified my design as below, is it fine ?

```
<user>
userid     username       groupid
1          john           1


<group>
groupid      groupname
1           admin
2           general
3           special 



<group_manage>
groupno    groupid      placeid
1          1            1
2          1            2
3          1            3
4          1            4  
5          2            1
6          2            2
7          2            3

<place>
placeid    placename   floor
1          A           1 
2          B           2 
3          C           3
4          D           4
```

Comment: the table should be called `groups-places` and you don't need the groupno column. It looks like it's just an id and in that case, if you still want it, name it `id`.